# Python selenium saying none when getting attribute for source of image

Tags: python, html, image, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm trying to get the src of the images in the class "KfFlO" using selenium(I am fairly new to this) however it does not seem to appear and python keeps printing "none" when I ask to print for the source. Does anyone know what the problem is? My code is listed below

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

url_muse="https://musescore.com/user/26033606/scores/6273879"

browser=webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(url_muse)

image_elements = browser.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,"KfFlO")

src=[]
for my_href in image_elements:
    src.append(my_href.get_attribute("href"))
print(src)
```

Thanks-Jake超新星

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To handle dynamic element use WebDriverWait() and wait for visibility_of_all_elements_located() and to get the `src` you need to use `get_attribute("src")`

```
url_muse="https://musescore.com/user/26033606/scores/6273879"

browser=webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(url_muse)
print([image.get_attribute("src") for image in WebDriverWait(browser,10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"img.KfFlO")))])
```

You need to import below libraries

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
```

Comment: Thanks for helping, however you forgot the close one of the brackets and when that is fixed it gives me the error "TypeError: visibility_of_all_elements_located() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given"

Comment: @jakeisthecoolest, It's a tuple, Just copy and paste my code, this will work.

Comment: print([image.get_attribute("src") for image in print([image.get_attribute("src") for image in WebDriverWait(browser,10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"img.KfFlO")))])
          ^
SyntaxError: '[' was never closed

Comment: @jakeisthecoolest, My bad. It was typo error and i didn't notice that. Please check now.